# QgsMapToolEmitPoint - output coordinate to QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgs, mapcanvas

I'm trying to output points to the QGIS Python Console with the following code which works:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
emit = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(emit)

def display(pt, e):
    print(f"{pt} {e}")

    
emit.canvasClicked.connect(display)
```

However if I change

```
canvas.setMapTool(emit)
```

to

```
cc = QgsMapTool(canvas)
canvas.setMapTool(cc)
```

The maptool is set on the canvas but nothing prints to the console and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QgsMapTool` is an abstract class. An abstract class cannot be instantiated. `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` inherites that class and provides a definition for the virtual functions in `QgsMapTool` class.

There is `QgsMapTool(QgsMapCanvas)` constructor method. It is a protected function. Protected functions are used by subclasses.

Comment: Great - thanks. Was getting completely confused with it. Why does it return without error:   ```cc = QgsMapTool(canvas)```   Thanks

Comment: There is a constructor method `QgsMapTool(QgsMapCanvas)` for subclasses.

Comment: Not sure I understand - could you expand a little further please. Thanks